# Read several lists from the text file properly python

Tags: python, list, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a text file which have 541 lists and each list has 280 numbers such as below:

```
[301.82779832839964, 301.84247725804647, 301.85718673070272, ..., 324.4056396484375, 324.20379638671875, 324.00198364257812]
                                   .
                                   .
[310.6907599572782, 310.68334604280966, 310.67756809346469,..., 324.23541883368551, 324.18277040240207, 324.09177971086382]
```

To read this text file, I used numpy.genfromtxt making a code to read the first list for the test such as:

```
pt1 = np.genfromtxt(filn1,dtype=np.float64,delimiter=",")
print pt1[0].shape
print list(pt1[0])
```

I expected that I could see the full list of the first list but the result list showed 'nan' in the first and the last place as below:

```
[nan, 301.84247725804647, 301.85718673070272, ...,  324.4056396484375, 324.20379638671875, nan]
```

I have tried other option in numpy.genfromtxt, I couldn't find why it resulted 'nan' in the first and the last place in the list. This event was not only for the first list, but also for all lists.

Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Thank you,

Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval
pt1 = np.array(map(literal_eval,open("in.txt")))
```

For:

```
[301.82779832839964, 301.84247725804647, 301.85718673070272,  324.4056396484375, 324.20379638671875, 324.00198364257812]
[310.6907599572782, 310.68334604280966, 310.67756809346469, 324.23541883368551, 324.18277040240207, 324.09177971086382]
```

You will get:

```
[[ 301.82779833  301.84247726  301.85718673  324.40563965  324.20379639
   324.00198364]
 [ 310.69075996  310.68334604  310.67756809  324.23541883  324.1827704
   324.09177971]]
```

Comment: Thank you Padraic. You solved my problem perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

It's applying 'nan' to the `[` and `]` in your files. As a last resort you could do something like this:

```
data = []
d = file('filn').read().split('\n')
for line in d:
    if line:
        data.append(eval(line))
data = np.asarray(data)
```

Alternatively you can replace the `[` and `]` for the whole file, and then you can use `np.genfromtxt(filn1,dtype=np.float64,delimiter=",")` like you were before, without getting and `nan` elements.

Comment: rather than `file.read().split('\n')`, you can just do `file.readlines()`

Comment: I know, thank you. I did that first, but for some reason it included the newlines in the results that way (each list item), which wasn't desired... so I was getting `[301.82779832839964, 301.8424772580465, 301.8571867307027, 324.4056396484375, 324.20379638671875, 324.0019836425781]\n` for some reason with `readlines()`.

Comment: oh yeah. the more common idiom is to use `strip` to get rid of the the `\n` but I suppose that's no better than your solution. btw the reason why you would use readlines instead of read is in case the file is too big to fit in memory.

Comment: aaah ah nice, i will edit it in a bit then and start using readlines, especially for big files :) Do you know the memory limit? Or I guess it's probably different for each machine...

Comment: if you're using 64 bit python, then the memory limit is just whatever ram your machine has, if you're on 32 bit then i think it's somewhere around 2-4 gb

Comment: @rofls: I appreciate for your answer. I did what you suggested, but I got the error of "data.append(eval(line))  File "<string>", line 0 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing". So I printed all data in 'd'. So, I could find some empty string at the end of this list complex: .... 324.18277040240207, 324.09177971086382]', '']. Do you have any idea for this ? Thank you.

Comment: I updated it. That happened because it was trying to do `eval` with the last line of the file, which was just an empy string. Testing to make sure the line has something in it fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is caused by the square brackets in your textfile; the simplest solution would be to remove these characters from your file, either just using find-replace in a text editor, or if you file is too large, by using a command-line tool like `sed`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have thought to remove all the square bracket, but it looked that it would take too much time. So I am looking for some easier solutions.